# How to take the row-wise maximum of columns with the same name

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe in R with lots of columns and lots of rows with numeric values. I have multiple colums with the same name (e.g. A, A, B, B, C, C...) that should be combined into a single colum with the maximum of the rows (A,B,C)

So this

| A | A | B | B | C | C | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | ... |
| 3 | 4 | 2 | 5 | 1 | 1 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Should be combined to

| A | B | C | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | ... |
| 4 | 5 | 1 | ... |
| ... |  |  |  |

Can somebody help me with that?

I found an example online that is used to summarize row values of columns with the same name

```
df<-
data.frame(x=rpois(25,1),y=rpois(25,2),x=rpois(25,5),z=rpois(25,2),y=rpois(25,1),z=rpoi
s(25,5),check.names=FALSE)
Merged_df<-as.data.frame(do.call(cbind,
by(t(df),INDICES=names(df),FUN=colSums)))
Merged_df
```

and replaced `FUN=colSums` it with

```
 FUN = function(x) max(x,na.rm = TRUE)
```

but that resulted in an error

```
Error in tapply(seq_len(3635L), list(INDICES = NULL), function (x)  : 
  arguments must have same length
```

Now i am not sure if this is a problem in my data or in the function i was using as i am not experienced with R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `split.default` to split the columns according to their names, and then get the rowwise max with `do.call` and `pmax`, before binding the rows.

```r
dat <- data.frame(A = 1:2, A = c(0, 3), B = 3:4, B = 0:1, check.names = F)
#   A A B B
# 1 1 0 3 0
# 2 2 3 4 1

split.default(dat, colnames(dat)) |>
  lapply(do.call, what = "pmax") |>
  rbind.data.frame()
#   A B
# 1 1 3
# 2 3 4
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. Will accept the answer as soon as it is possible.